# Is there any possibility of getting some performance gain on fstream (file read) by using openMP

Tags: c++, openmp, fstream

I would like to know whether there might be any possibility of some performance gain on file read by using openMP.

Example code,

```
fstream file;

file.open("test.txt",ios::in);

file.seekg(0,ios::end);

int len = file.tellg();

char *arr = new char[len];

char *temp = new char[1];

int i;

#pragma omp parallel for shared(arr, len) private(temp, i)
for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    file.seekg(i);
    file.read(temp,1);
    arr[i] = temp[0];
}
```

I guess using multiple threads for I/O operation is a bad option because finally file read operation will be serialized. But still, I would like to whether one can expect a performance gain. Moreover, I would also like to know how does openMP handles the parallel file read operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, you're not likely to get any speedup parallelizing any sort of I/O bound task like this. However, there is a much bigger problem. The code isn't even correct.

The `seekg()` and `read()` methods modify the `file` variable. So your iterations aren't independent. So you will have race conditions on the stream. In other words, **the loop isn't parallelizable.**

So don't expect that code to work at all - let alone with better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are lots of performance improvements in file streams those you are proposing are not among them:

- `std::streambuf` is stateful and trying to access it simultanously from multiple threads of execution will thoroughly mess it up.
- Processing individual characters is essentially a worst case scenario for a contemporary processor. If you really end up doing it in parallel you'd have multiple processors messing with the same cache lines. This will actually dramatically degrade performance compared to a single thread of execution.
- I don't know why people are so.fond of using seeks: each seek essentially kills any current buffer and may cause a system call just to position the stream to a defined state. The key problem with seeking is that sets the stream up to be either for reading or writing, depending what is the next operation. Yes, the open mode may be taken into account but it probably isn't.

If you want to read a fast approach to read a file using `std::ifstream` you should

- `imbue()` a `std::locale` which advertises not to do any conversion
- open the file in `std::binary` mode
- **skip** trying to get what may be a wrong estimate on the size of the file (seeking to the end and hoping that this somehow gives you the number of characters in a file is futile)
- read the to a suitable `std::ostream` e.g. `std::ostringstream` (if you can provide the destination buffer you can use a faster output stream) using the  output operator for stream buffers: `out << in.rdbuf()`

  I don't see that concurreny would help you with reading a stream.